# CS50 week 4 Filter-less Blur Function

Tags: c, cs50, blur

I spent several day trying to figure out what's wrong with this function. It actually compile fine but it blurs the image in the wrong way. I believe maybe my numbers or formulas are wrong but after checking it again and again for several hours I cannot figure out what s wrong.

The exercise wants you  to blur an image using a 3*3 blur box so adding up the RGB values of the blur box and dividing them by the valid blur box pixels (the ones in side the image boundaries).Then assigning the 'blurred' values to the image.

In my blurred image the blur does not allow to distinguish any figure in the picture. I checked other blur function answers and tried to make and re-make the code from scratch with different variations but nothing seems to work. The code below it seems to me it s the closer to the right solution.
Any help would be very much appreciate.
Sorry for any mistake in my english

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{    // create image copy for holding modifies RGB values
     RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
     for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {
              copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
         }
     }
     // setting variable for holding sum of blur box RGB values
     float blurred = 0.0;
     float blurgreen = 0.0;
     float blurblue = 0.0;
     // setting counter for valid blur box pixels
     float validpixels = 0.0;
     // looping through image rows
     for( int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {   // looping through image columns
         for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {   // looping through blur box rows
             for(int r = -1; r < 2; r++)
             {   //looping through blur box columns
                 for(int c = -1; c < 2; c++)
                 {   // counting only valid blur-box pixels(inside image boundaries)
                     if(i + c >= 0 && j + r >= 0 && i + c < height && j + r < width)
                     {  // storing total of blur box RGB values
                        blurred += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtRed;
                        blurgreen += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtGreen;
                        blurblue += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtBlue;
                        // counting valid pixels total
                        validpixels ++;
                     }
                 }
             }
               // calculate RGB  blurred values and assigning them to image copy
               copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(blurred / validpixels);
               copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(blurgreen / validpixels);
               copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blurblue / validpixels);
         }
     }
     //giving blur values back to image
     for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {
              image[i][j].rgbtRed = copy[i][j].rgbtRed;
              image[i][j].rgbtGreen = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;
              image[i][j].rgbtBlue = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue;
         }
     }
    return;
}
```

Comment: "I spent several day" You should start to run your programs in a debugger. Stepping through your code while watching variables changes should reveal such obvious errors rather quickly. It may be possible to solve problems by staring at the code but there is no need to waste your time doing that.

Comment: Can you add an image of the original image and an image with the outcome you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks for taking the time and answering. You are right about the debugger there was even a part of a previous lesson of CS50 about using it but for some reason I try to fix my code using google searches and re-watching the lesson. I will definitely learn how it works and start to use it from now.

Comment: @DragosRizescu thanks Dragos but I think there is no more need since the help from the other guys solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 main issues:

- You must re-initialize your `blur*` variables and also the counter for each pixel. Otherwise you keep summing up more and more pixels. That will basically create an average of the whole image when you get to the end.
- You are storing blurred values in the same array where you read the values to blur. That spills the whole purpose of making a copy at all.

Not an issue but could be improved:

- Do not use `float` in your programs. Unless you have some very strict limitations in memory or computing power, you should always use `double` for floating point numbers.
- Counters are best defined as integers, not floating point numbers.
- Pointed out by Chux: As your destination is an integer value, you could replace `round` by `lround`. Or use integer arithmetics all the way as shown in Chux's answer.

The fixes are marked in the code using `//####`

```c
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{    // create image copy for holding modifies RGB values
     RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
     for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {
              copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
         }
     }

     // looping through image rows
     for( int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {   // looping through image columns
         for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {   // looping through blur box rows

             // setting variable for holding sum of blur box RGB values
             //#### Initialize your blurring variables for each pixel you are visiting.
             //#### Always use double instead of float except you have specific requirements.
             double blurred = 0.0;
             double blurgreen = 0.0;
             double blurblue = 0.0;

             // setting counter for valid blur box pixels
             //#### Also re-initialize counter for each pixel
             //#### Counters are normally integers, no floating point numbers
             size_t validpixels = 0;

             for(int r = -1; r < 2; r++)
             {   //looping through blur box columns
                 for(int c = -1; c < 2; c++)
                 {   // counting only valid blur-box pixels(inside image boundaries)
                     if(i + c >= 0 && j + r >= 0 && i + c < height && j + r < width)
                     {  // storing total of blur box RGB values
                        blurred += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtRed;
                        blurgreen += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtGreen;
                        blurblue += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtBlue;
                        // counting valid pixels total
                        validpixels ++;
                     }
                 }
             }
               // calculate RGB  blurred values and assigning them to image copy
               //#### No! Don't store in the copy again. This will disturb
               //#### calculation of the other pixels. 
               image[i][j].rgbtRed = lround(blurred / validpixels);
               image[i][j].rgbtGreen = lround(blurgreen / validpixels);
               image[i][j].rgbtBlue = lround(blurblue / validpixels);
         }
     }
     //giving blur values back to image
     //#### No! Copying again is not required. Results were stored there already

    return;
}
```

Comment: Consider `lround()` instead of `round()` since the target is an integer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand my mistakes ware to not re-initialize each variable back to 0 for each loop so that result of the previous loop was affecting the calculation of the following loop and to assign the values to the copy instead than to the image directly again affecting the calculation of the following loops, Thanks again  I  spent no less than 12-14 hours on this blur function, I 'll definitely use a debugger from now on.

Answer (score 0):

> Any help would be very much appreciate.

Not a fix to a problem, but a simplification.

```
 //for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
 //    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
 //         copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
 //    }
 //}
 memcpy(copy, image, sizeof copy);
```

Likewise with final copy back to `image`.  Yet since copy is not needed, just drop this step.

```
// memcpy(image, copy, sizeof copy);
```

Do not use `sizeof image` as that is not the size of the image.

---

Rather than `float` math, stay with integer math.

```
 // float blurred = 0.0;
 unsigned blurred = 0;
 // float validpixels = 0.0;
 unsigned validpixels = 0;
  
   ...
   // Leave as is.
   blurred += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtRed;
   ... 
      // copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(blurred / validpixels);
      // Put result in `image[]`
      image[i][j].rgbtRed = (blurred + validpixels/2) / validpixels;
```

---

Rather than test `r` in the deepest loop:

```
             {   //looping through blur box columns
                 for(int c = -1; c < 2; c++)
                 {   // counting only valid blur-box pixels(inside image boundaries)
                     if(i + c >= 0 && j + r >= 0 && i + c < height && j + r < width)
                     {  // storing total of blur box RGB values
                        blurred += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtRed;
                        blurgreen += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtGreen;
                        blurblue += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtBlue;
                        // counting valid pixels total
                        validpixels ++;
                     }
                 }
             }
```

Move the test and reset the `validpixels`

```
             unsigned blurred = 0;
             unsigned blurgreen = 0;
             unsigned blurblue = 0;
             unsigned validpixels = 0;
             for(int r = -1; r < 2; r++) {
                 // Add 
                 if(!(j + r >= 0 && j + r < width)) continue;
                 for(int c = -1; c < 2; c++) {
                     // if(i + c >= 0 && j + r >= 0 && i + c < height && j + r < width)
                     if(i + c >= 0 && i + c < height) {
                        blurred += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtRed;
                        blurgreen += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtGreen;
                        blurblue += copy[i + c][j + r].rgbtBlue;
                        validpixels ++;
                     }
                 }
             }
```

---

**Advanced**

Division can be expensive in time.  As the vast majority of divisions is by 9, consider:

```
      image[i][j].rgbtRed = validpixels == 9 ? 
          (blurred + 9/2) / 9 :
          (blurred + validpixels/2) / validpixels;
```

With optimizations turned on, the compiler is certain to create  faster code with a fixed divisor of 9, even with the `validpixels == 9` overheard.

Comment: Thank you chux I understand now where my code was wrong. The only thing I don't understand of your answer is the  'Advanced'  part. What does the  first line means? if I have to guess I would say 'in those array position only if valid pixels are 9' do the following?. The other 2 lines I dont understand them at all. Why divide by 2 and what : means? Thanks if you want to unswer

Comment: @Nico "'in those array position only if valid pixels are 9' do the following?" --> Yes.  "Why divide by 2" replaces the floating `round()` with an integer _round_.  Recall integer division `a/b` truncates away the fraction.  With `(a + b/2)/b`, we get a rounded quotient for _unsigned_ math.